# Django testing external script

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to perform testing on a script that interacts with my Django application, namely the database. Normally, when we want to test something in Django we simply fire up the built in test suite. With this test suite we even get nice command line switches such as overriding the built in `settings.py` with a different settings file:

```
python manage.py test myApp --settings='settings_test'
```

Here is the problem:

1) I want to test said script which is not part of an app, so I know of no way to invoke the test suite using `manage.py`. Is this possible? I.e.:

```
python manage.py test /path/myScript.py --settings='settings_test'
```

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Red-headed-step-child `Django-NonRel` which is `Django==1.5.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use a different test runner.

You can do `pip install django-nose` and then set the following setting in your `test_settings.py`

```
TEST_RUNNER = `django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner`
```

Now you can run the tests with

```
./manage.py test --settings=yourproject.test_settings.py
```

and the Nose testrunner will search all subfolders for folders called `tests` and in those folders it will search for files that end with `_tests.py` (and in those files it will search for classes that derive from `TestCase`, as usual).

So your project structure should look something like this:

```
- Project-Root/
  - Your-Non-App-Code/
    - __init__.py
    - non_app_code.py
    - tests/
      - __init__.py
      - non_app_code_tests.py
```

For more info on how to install django-nose, check their Github repo: https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose

Comment: I'll look into this, and it might take me a while before I can upvote, but it seems like legit information. Also, the solution looks a little like what a native Django solution might be. Example, move the external test script into the Django project folder exactly as you indicated. That's because `Django < 1.6` expects `MyApp.TestCase.test` structure. Thanks again.

Comment: Played around with `django_nose` for the past 3 days. This was a solid lead... Now I have coverage reports and totally hacked html test summary report output. Most of all, as you indicated, I can now perform my non-app tests without destroying the dev database. Thank you!